# Reduction of carboxylic acids by LiAlH4

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

I've read that when a carboxylic acid reacts with $\ce{LiAlH4}$ the corresponding alcohol is formed:

[image]

But when I try to think of the mechanism, I get stuck here:

$\ce{LiAlH4}$ produces $\ce{H-}$. Since $\ce{H-}$ is a strong base it should immediately abstract a proton from the carboxylic acid to give the corresponding carboxylate ion (just like in the reaction of carboxylic acids with Grignard reagents), instead of undergoing nucleophilic addition to give the alcohol.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I am curious to know where you read that reduction of the carboxylate to form two alcohols. Do you have a link? The other oxygen becomes attached to the aluminum species as shown in Jerry's answer. Now, a [carboxylic acid anhydride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anhydride) is a different beast altogether. Anhydrides will reduce to a pair of alcohols.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The $\ce{Li^+}$ ion substitutes the $\ce{OH}$ in $\ce{COOH}$ first. The $\ce{C=O}$ is then reduced by $\ce{AlH_3}$ to give an aldehyde. See below:

[image]

Another $\ce{LiAlH_4}$ then reduces the aldehyde to alcohol:
[image]

I found the pictures [here](http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/vlu_organik/c_acid/reaktionen_organoli_carbons.vlu/Page/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/c_acid/organoli/organoli.vscml.html).

Comment: $\ce{LiAlH4}$ is such a powerful reducing agent that it will attack carboxylate anions (which are resistant to most other nucleophiles).