# Can H– act as a strong Brønsted base like CH3–?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, organic-reduction

In the reduction of carboxylic acids with $\ce {LiAlH_4}$ we get an alcohol. But isn't there a possibility of the hydride donor abstracting $\ce {H^{+}}$ from the acid to form $\ce {H_2}$?

Comment: You are right. The hydride would first act as a base deprotonating the acid before performing the hydride attack and subsequently reducing it.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/reduction-of-carboxylic-acids-by-lialh4?rq=1